# Sum of a series ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series as- (2)(2) + (4)(4)+ (7)(8)+ (11)(16)+(16)(32)+... and I can't successfully figure out its sum.I tried finding the nth term and arranging it into a difference.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without full context, it appears as though your series you are adding numbers that grow increasingly larger.  You write for example $(11)(16)$ which to me reads as $11\times 16 = 176$.  Do you mean perhaps to write instead $\frac{11}{16}$?  What rule do your terms follow?  What is the $n$'th term in the sum?  If you are unable to answer or provide more context, then there is not nearly enough information to help with.

Comment: The nth term would be (n^2+n+2)(2^n-1)

Comment: Every term is the product of a corresponding term of a series whose difference is in AP and 2^n

Comment: Your attempt at an $n$'th term is not correct.  Notice that $n^2+n+2$ is *always* even, but you have odd factors (*numerators?*) appearing.  You should also be more careful about using enough parentheses, `2^n-1` reads as $2^n - 1$ (*e.g. 1,3,7,15,31,...*) instead of as $2^{n-1}$ (*1,2,4,8,16,32,...*).  You still have not inserted any slash or division symbol or any other way of making it look like a fraction, which implies to me that maybe these aren't fractions at all and the terms really are increasing in an unbounded manner.  If terms do not approach zero, the series can never converge.

Comment: These are not fractions but products

Comment: If you want to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{N} a_n$ you have to provide for $n_0$ and $N$ (eventually infinite) and $a_n$. As for now, it looks like an infinite sum of non-zero-convergent terms thus value is infinite!

Comment: [$n$'th-term test for divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: I think OP just wants to find the $n$th term. However the question is seriously lacking

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JMoravitz commented, you want to compute
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k (n^2+n+2)\,2^{n-1}$$ So, consider $$T_k=\sum_{n=1}^k (n^2+n+2)\,x^{n-1}$$ and write
$$n^2+n+2=n(n-1)+2n+2$$making
$$T_k=\sum_{n=1}^k n(n-1)\,x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=1}^k n\,x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=1}^k x^{n-1}$$ and recognize a trivial summation and its first and second derivatives.

Comment: Which have radius of convergence $1$ and to be applied at $x=2$. It may not work so well... :p

Comment: @zwim. As Dylan commented, it is not said that $k\to \infty$. Otherwise, for sure, no need to compute anything. Cheers.